# I've installed a library into my /usr/local directory. I would now like to include this directory into my CMakeLists.txt. How do I do this?

Tags: c++, cmake, mujoco

I have installed a library onto my system and I would now like to import this library to build with cmake in my CMakeLists.txt file but I'm not able to import it. I get errors that the library can't be found when I run `cmake ..`

The library was installed to `/usr/local` and it is in a few sub folders here. I have them all listed below.

This is the part of my CMakeLists.txt which fails.

```
find_package(MUJOCO REQUIRED)
link_libraries(MUJOCO::mujoco)
```

This is the error I get with this attempt to import the library in my CMakeLists.txt

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:65 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindMUJOCO.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "MUJOCO", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "MUJOCO" with any
  of the following names:

    MUJOCOConfig.cmake
    mujoco-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "MUJOCO" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "MUJOCO_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "MUJOCO"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

This is where the mujoco library was installed on my system, the library I want to include was installed.
I'm not sure it is write to hand code every one of these paths.

```
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/basic
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/compile
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/derivative
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/record
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/testspeed
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/testxml
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/simulate
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libmujoco.so.2.2.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libmujoco.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/mujoco/mjdata.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/mujoco/mjexport.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/mujoco/mjmodel.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/mujoco/mjrender.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/mujoco/mjtnum.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/mujoco/mjui.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/mujoco/mjvisualize.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/mujoco/mjxmacro.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/mujoco/mujoco.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/mujoco/mujocoTargets.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/mujoco/mujocoTargets-release.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/mujoco/mujocoConfig.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/mujoco/mujocoConfigVersion.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/hammock
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/hammock/humanoid_body.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/hammock/hammock.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/tendon_arm
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/tendon_arm/arm26.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/composite
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/composite/scene.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/composite/cloth.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/composite/softbox.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/composite/asset
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/composite/asset/sponge.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/composite/asset/marble.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/composite/asset/carpet.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/composite/loop.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/composite/particle.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/composite/rope.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/composite/grid2pin.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/humanoid
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/humanoid/22_humanoids.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/humanoid/humanoid.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/flag
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/flag/flag.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/mug
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/mug/mug.obj
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/mug/mug.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/mug/mug.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/slider_crank
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/slider_crank/slider_crank.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/humanoid100
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/humanoid100/humanoid100.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mujoco/model/humanoid100/humanoid_body.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only cmake configuration files installed by the lib are

```
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/mujoco/mujocoTargets.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/mujoco/mujocoTargets-release.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/mujoco/mujocoConfig.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/mujoco/mujocoConfigVersion.cmake
```

```
find_package(<Package> ...)
```

in config mode checks for the files

```
<package>-config.cmake
<Package>Config.cmake
```

where `<package>` is the `<Package>` with the first character converted to lower case.

, see the [`find_package()` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html)

You've used `find_package(MUJOCO REQUIRED)` in your cmake project, which means, cmake is looking for a file named `mujoco-config.cmake` or `MUJOCOConfig.cmake`, but not for `mujocoConfig.cmake`.

You need to use

```
find_package(mujoco REQUIRED)
```

instead.

Comment: I think a key point is linux has case sensitive filesystems so you have to be careful with case.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to have imported the library without error, but now I'm back to a situation I was before where I can `#include` the library but I can't use anything in it. I get `undefined reference` for everything in it. I wonder if this is still a cmake problem or problem with the library.

Comment: You should use target_link_libraries() also any question about a linker error would be better served in a new question since it's a completely different topic / problem than the one in this question.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you. This command is in the bottom of my CMakeLists.txt and there are a few other libraries "linked" such as `${GSL_LIBRARIES}` and I am able to include and use it. For mujoco I've tried `${mujoco}` `${mujoco_LIBRARIES}` and  `${MUJOCO_LIBRARIES}` no error for any variation but I can't use the library in my C++. It does deserve a new question. I just fear asking new questions here.

Comment: @drescherjm I think `link_libraries(mujoco::mujoco)` just did it. Thank you. I wouldn't know these combinations would need to be worked out if it wasn't for help of people like you. Is this in docs somewhere? Where do you learn these things?